# Selecting array fields from Mongoose results

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have documents with several fields including an array of other documents. I can successfully query my target documents and fetch most fields, but I can't fetch the arrays for some reason.

Here's a little snippet of how I'm querying documents and fetching fields:

```
Asset.findOne({
    project: asset.project,
    ip: asset.ip
}, function(err, match) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (match) {
        console.log(match);
        console.log(match.project);
        console.log(match.traffic);
    });
});
```

And here's an example of the console log:

```
{ __v: 0,
  project: 'test',
  traffic: 
   [ { rport: 39110,
       protocol: 'tcp',
       destination: '10.0.7.30',
       lport: 50 },
     { rport: 49123, protocol: 'tcp', source: '10.0.7.29', lport: 21 } ],
  mac: 'update',
  ip: '10.0.7.27',
  _id: 568fbd22ca70246a168d45aa }

test

undefined
```

As you can see `console.log(match)` gives us the whole document. This document has a `project` field which I can get with `match.project`. However `match.traffic` returns `undefined`. As you can see, there is definitely a `traffic` array field in the returned document.

**How can I access arrays from my documents?**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some mongoose issue, where mongoose returns a mongoose object instead of a javascript object.

Try this.

`Model.find(query).lean().exec(callback)`

this will convert the mongoose object to a javascript object, but you would lose mongoose functions like `obj.save()`